# How to change the case of the last letter in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, lowercase

So I want to change the last character in a string to lower case. The code below is the method I am using to print a string backwards, but list leaves the last character as a capital and I can't figure out how to fix this!

```
        if s[-1] == "x":
            new = ""
            last_index = len(s)-1
            for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):
                new += s[i]
            s = new
            s = "".join(word[0].upper() + word[1:] for word in s.split())
        print (s)
```

e.g:
The input is:

```
Inbox
```

and this outputs:

```
XobnI
```

But I want it to output:

```
Xobni
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Use `str.title`:

```
>>> "Inbox"[::-1].title()
'Xobni'
```

Comment: And, with one fell swoop, you not only solve the _specific_ problem but also reduce the code required by the whole thing by about 90%. +1, but only because I couldn't +5 :-)